# Is it possible to track User's Location when app is killed (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, plugins, location

I am trying to track user's location when app is killed and send that location(Latitude and Longitude) to a database(Firestore) in Flutter.

I am a newbie and so I have no idea how to do this. It would be appreciated if someone could help me on this one.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Getting a users location in the background in real time is not really possible since android 8 as they limited how often we can get GPS data for an app running in the background. Furthermore this is really not recommended - Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I’m trying to create a safety app wherein the user’s location is stored on a database and that location can be viewed from another phone. Is it possible to do the tracking at least every 10 or 15 minutes? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to fetch the device's location data while the app is running in the background. You mentioned that you'd like to achieve this even when the app is killed - by "killed", if you mean here fetching location data after being forced stop in Android, then this isn't possible.

If you like to fetch user data while the app is running the background, you can use the [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) plugin. Though doing so have privacy implications, and you'll need to request permission from the user. The permission request is built-in to the `geolocator` plugin.

```dart
LocationPermission permission;

permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
```

After this you can then listen to the Stream and update the code snippet with however you want to store the location data.

```dart
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

final LocationSettings locationSettings = LocationSettings(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);

StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings).listen(
    (Position? position) {
    print(position == null ? 'Unknown' : '${position.latitude.toString()}, ${position.longitude.toString()}');
    // Store geolocation data
});
```

To run the tasks in the background even when the app isn't running in the foreground, you can use [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager).

Create a Workmanager for running the task and initialize it on the Flutter project's `main.dart`.

```dart
void locationHandler() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((_) {
    print('background task running'); 
    
    // Fetch device location data
  });
}

void main() {
  Workmanager().initialize(
    locationHandler, // The top level function, aka callbackDispatcher
    isInDebugMode: true // If enabled it will post a notification whenever the task is running. Handy for debugging tasks
  );
  Workmanager().registerOneOffTask('yourTaskName', 'yourTaskNameDescription);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: does it work ON API 33?